# Save several data in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I need to tell the game which items the user just bought, and save this data (just the bought items) so then I can put a related code.
I was thinking of saving like a list of items in a string, and then check it.
Does it exist a better way to do something like this?

Comment: Find my answer below, its to promote you to learn instead of directly saving to a file on the local machine, you could take this information and send it via a packet through networking / including encryption to a said location. then pull the information back. The answer below will save on bandwidth a string is 1 byte per character we push 1 byte below per item.. -Levon

Comment: Although levon points at a few decent points, it is not always necessary to use a network/database to store data. If you are simply designing a game for practice or even a single player game where no in app purchases are used, it is perfectly fine to keep it lightweight and locally.

Answer (score 0):

If its a simple single player game, then you can store your items as JSON object either in playerprefs (if its not too long) or simply write down the Json to a txt file and store it on the device.

JSON looks like this :

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

But it is makes it much easier to read and parse items unlike string, where you will have to come up with your way of parsing if you are trying to save several parameters. You can use JsonUtility which comes with unity, or Newtonsoft.JSON which is a free asset.